# Как с помощью python3 имитировать полностью работу браузера, а именно получить CSRF token?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

**Главный вопрос (кратко): Как получить X-CSRFToken от сервера с помощью питона?**

Я пишу скрпит (я только начал учить питон), который **должен авторизироваться** на [сайте](https://worldoftanks.ru/) и потом уже производить какие-то действия дальше.

Пробую это сделать с помощью библиотеки **requests**, но в итоге мне сервер отвечает **ошибка 403** (в доступе отказано), думаю из-за не правильного **CSRFToken**, т.к. копировал его из запроса, который поймал в сниффере.
Часть кода, отвечающего за авторизацию:

```
import requests

url_Authorization_POST = "https://ru.wargaming.net/id/signin/process/" #взял ссылку с помощью сниффера
data_Authorization_POST = {
"captcha" : "",
"login" : "abcde@gmail.com", #в скритпе 100% правильный логин, тут заменил
"next" : "/id/sso/signin/notify/?next=/id/openid/682672221766093688/&trust_root=https%3A%2F%2Fworldoftanks.ru%2F" # 682672221766093688 каждый раз меняется, не знаю что это,
"password" : "MyPassword", #в скритпе 100% правильный пароль, тут заменил
"type" : "pow", 
"pow" : "22729" #Это значение каждый раз меняется, когда слежу за запросом в сниффере, не знаю что это такое, если знаете - подскажите)}    

headers_Authorization_POST = {
"Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
"Origin": "https://ru.wargaming.net",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36",
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
"Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
"X-CSRFToken": "mLVr2shF6b4BsjESGxwPmlau1xm4cRmS", #Вот он, собака, как его получить с помощью питона???
"DNT": "1",
"Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors"}

Session = requests.session()
Session.post(urlAuthorization_POST, data=authorizationData_POST, headers=authorizationHeaders_POST)
```

В ответе на запрос, как и писал - ошибка 403.

Скрин, где находится этот токен на сайте.

[Ссылка](https://ru-wotp.wgcdn.co/static/5.45.1_053b48/csrf/js/csrf.js)  на скрипт

**Код из скрина**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            csrf.init({
                COOKIE_NAME: "csrftoken",
                COOKIE_URL: "/set_csrf_cookie/"
            });

            window.Settings = window.Settings || {};
            window.Settings.CSRF_TOKEN = csrf.token;
        })
    </script>
```

[image: где находится этот токен на сайте]

Comment: 1. CSRF токен - он [одноразовый](https://habr.com/ru/post/318748/) 2. Тут используется javascript, поэтому либо начинаем "распутывать клубок" как это работает, и начинаем "эмулировать" браузер, либо используем [selenium](https://pythonspot.com/selenium/). 3. Если это покажется сложным, возьмите сайт попроще, где нет таких защит - для обучения.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно авторизация на сайте делается так:

1. Запрашивается страница авторизации GET-ом.
2. Возвращённая сервером страница разбирается, из неё вытаскиваются данные для авторизации.
3. В данные добавляется логин и пароль и отправляется запрос на сервер
4. Профит. :)

Да, ещё некоторые сайты могут поддерживать базовую авторизацию - она напрямую поддерживается пакетом `requests`